# Why is the Windows 10 Photos app #1 on my list of network usage?

Tags: windows-10, bandwidth

I only use the Photos app when I double-click local image files (it's the default).

How is this my **#1 bandwidth user** in the last 30 days as per the App History tab on the Task Manager.

That puts it above things like OneNote, which I use heavily and syncs to the cloud with every change.

What exactly is it using network bandwidth for when I'm only using it with local files?

Comment: have activated the option to upload all pictures to OneDrive?

Comment: @magicandre1981 Yes, that could explain it, but how does that tie into the Windows Photo app itself?  That is an image viewer, it shouldn't have anything to do with syncing to the cloud.  Of course, I'm probably wrong about that.  These days, all sorts of mysterious stuff going on behind the scenes.  And I'm a Microsoft software developer!

Comment: @magicandre1981 I looked into this further, and I am apparently NOT syncing any folder photos to OneDrive.  I went into the cloud account and browsed around, and it has stuff from My Documents but it doesn't have any photos.  So we're back to square one.

Comment: Does running `resmon` tell you which network the Photos app is connecting to?

Comment: And unchecking "show my cloud-only content from OneDrive" in Photos app settings have any effect?..

Comment: @w32sh I have not used `resmon` yet but I've played around with other over-the-wire tools like Fiddler and WireShark and I don't see it making any outbound connections to the public internet.  However, it has hundreds of megabytes above the next closest app in my list in terms of network activity, when I would expect zero.

Comment: @w32sh I didn't even notice that setting regarding OneDrive cloud content.  I've shut that off.  That may be what the issue is here.  I'll keep an eye on it.  In my opinion, an image VIEWER should not be ranking #1 in terms of bandwidth.  I don't care if it has to sync with OneDrive, that should be a setting in OneDrive itself and not an image viewer!  Why is a viewer trying to synchronize with the cloud?  This should be done behind the scenes via a OneDrive service based on your settings.

Answer (score -2):

They are uploading your pictures to their AI for auto-tagging without your consent.  Also, the DLC mediaengine addon is installed without your consent.  They will let you delete it, and then they stealthily re-install it minutes, hours, or weeks later (it seems random; I can't figure out why)- ostensibly after you are satisfied that it is gone.  This happens to me routinely.  I have had enough of it- when I say "uninstall the feature as it wastes my bandwidth"; I don't mean REINSTALL it when I'm not looking and upload gigabytes of my personal photos to the internet!  And build a extensive advertisement profile for me using said photos. Or perhaps they are trying to fight terrorism or child pornography?  Whatever the cause, it costs me valuable data and makes my machine sluggish.

Why doesn't anybody seem to know this?  Microsoft doesn't seem to have a press release about this service... why not?

Comment: Do you have any references to back up your claims?